# Where's top margin actually measured from?

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm typesetting a book using `memoir` class as follow.

1. Final book size: 14 x 21 cm
2. Two side
3. Has running headers.
4. Margin: inside=0.75in, others=0.5in

The header/page number section is just too close to the top page edge. There should be enough space between them.

My questions:

1. Where's top margin actually measured from? from most top paragraph to the
   top edge of page, or from header to the top edge of page.
2. How to properly set the margin (inside=0.75in, others=0.5in) and page size (14x21 cm).

Thanks. :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm, paperheight=210mm, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in, outer=0.5in, inner=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Let's do it
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should see p 8 of the [`layouts` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf), which shows the construction of the page dimensions.

Comment: Gary don't you just use memoirs own layout system instead of geometry? Top margin is from the top of the paper to the top of the text block. Then there is a further topskip down to the baseline of the first line of text

Comment: The header is *inside* the top margin, and as far as I know the only way to set an absolute distance from the top of the page to the top of the *header* is to set the `\uppermargin` to your desired length and then add to it manually the height of your header. There must be a better way.

Comment: When you say the margin should be `x` what do you mean? Should this include the header (at the top)? The footer (at the bottom)? The margin notes (at the side)?

Comment: @Cfr: I used to assume that top margin is measured from most top paragraph to the top edge of page, until I saw the result. I thought I've misunderstood. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks, Daleif. I'm pretty new to LaTeX. Just tried to put some `codes` which might work for me. I `learn` by `mistakes` and `errors`.

Comment: @Ekosan Well that *is* the top margin, isn't it? But the running head is not part of the text block so it does not count as the top paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

This is just an illustration of the method you might use, based on a very quick skim of [memoir's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). No doubt you have more specific ideas about the dimensions you want but the key is to use `memoir`'s abilities, rather than fighting them by loading `geometry`. (Otherwise, use a standard class such as `book` and then `geometry` is a great idea.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setstocksize{210mm}{140mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{.75in}{.5in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{\dimexpr.5in+\baselineskip}{\dimexpr.5in+\baselineskip}{*}
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image: page spread with memoir]

Comment: Thanks, Cfr. I forgot to mention. The running header should sit in the middle of `top margin`, instead of stick to the top edge (as sample image shown above). I might have to adjust the `top` margin to 0.75 in.

Comment: @Ekosan I don't really understand. Which 'top edge' is it 'sticking' to? `memoir`'s documentation is extremely detailed. Given that you know what you want to do, I think it would be easiest if you would look through the documentation to get a clearer idea of how things work, and then edit your question accordingly. (But somebody else may understand better than I do.)

Comment: Oh, sorry Cfr, It's my fault. I mean `as my previous sceenshot above` (not the screenshot you've just uploaded above). Really sorry...

Comment: Okay. I'll dive deeper into `memoir docs` soon. Thanks a lot.